# How can I delete rows that have same information but in different columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I'm using a postgresql database with pgAdmin and I've a table that consists in 2 columns, column init and column end so all the rows in the table have and identical one but with the data in the opposite columns. Is there a way to delete all the rows that contains the same data in different columns keeping one of them? Like this:

```
 Init - End   
1 A       B
2 B       A
3 C       D
4 D       E
5 D       C
6 E       D
```

I would like to delete row 2,4 and 5.

Comment: Why delete D,E and not E,D?

Comment: Becouse I've two rows with duplicated data, but i want to keep one of them.

Comment: I know that you want to keep one of them. But there must be a pattern. If from A,B and B,A you want to delete B,A then from D,E and E,D you should delete E,D and not D,E. This is why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EXISTS:

```
delete from tablename t
where 
  t."Init" > t."End" 
  and
  exists (
    select 1 from tablename
    where "End" = t."Init" and "Init" = t."End"
  );
```

This code will keep the row (for example) A,B and delete the row B,A.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/89S7sHtA8StR9zRntLwzv6/1).
Results:

```
| Init | End |
| ---- | --- |
| A    | B   |
| C    | D   |
| D    | E   |
```